# How to use two triggers on a fancybox gallery when one trigger isn't an image?

Tags: jquery, triggers, fancybox, fancybox-2

**SETUP:**

We have a layout that contains:

- Gallery A triggered by thumbs
- Gallery B triggered by thumbs
- An a tag used as a second trigger for Gallery A

Gallery A (thumbs) looks like this:

```
<a class="open-fancybox" href="<?= $image->url() ?>" rel="product-main-gallery">
  <img src="<?= thumb($image, array('width' => 355), false) ?>" alt="<?= $image->name() ?>">
</a>
```

The a tag for the secondary trigger looks like this:

```
<a class="open-fancybox" href="<?= $firstImage->url(); ?>" rel="product-main-gallery"</a>
```

**ISSUES:**

On the secondary trigger, the URL for the first image in Gallery A is being used - but when clicked, the first image is displayed twice.

If we use `href="#"` instead, Gallery A opens but the first image is blank.

**QUESTION:**

How can we use an a tag as a secondary trigger for Gallery A?

Our javascript is a bit green so any pointers would be much appreciated - for reference, the galleries are being initialised like this:

```
<script>
  // Initialise fancy-box: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/
  $(function() {
    $(".open-fancybox").fancybox({
      openEffect  : 'fade',
      closeEffect : 'elastic',
      nextEffect  : 'fade',
      prevEffect  : 'fade',
      nextSpeed   : 'slow',
      prevSpeed   : 'slow',
      arrows      : 'true',

      // configure overlay style (for full screen image as per below)
      padding     : 0,
      margin      : 0,
      autoCenter   : false,

      helpers : {
        // configure overlay colour
        overlay : {
          css : {
            'background' : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)'
          }
        }
      },

      // force overlay image to full screen: http://jsfiddle.net/2XhjG/
      afterLoad  : function () {
        $.extend(this, {
          aspectRatio : false,
          type    : 'html',
          width   : '100%',
          height  : '100%',
          content : '<div class="fancybox-image" style="background-image:url(' + this.href + '); background-size: cover; background-position:50% 50%;background-repeat:no-repeat;height:100%;width:100%;" /></div>'
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always trigger a fancybox gallery with another `<a>` link (or another element as a matter of fact) that doesn't need to belong to the gallery itself (it can be a thumbnail or simple text)

You have (at least) two options :

1). Trigger the gallery using the attribute `onclick` (from your trigger) like :

```
<a href="image.jpg" onclick="$('a.fancybox').eq(0).trigger('click'); return false;">trigger fancybox gallery</a>
```

**Notice** that we are targeting the first element of the gallery via the `.eq()` method. Of course, we should have the selector `.fancybox` (`.open-fancybox` in your case) bound to fancybox.

2). Bind a `click` event to your trigger like

```
<a class="trigger" href="image.jpg">I am another trigger</a>
```

**Notice** we added the class `.trigger` to the element, then

```
$(".trigger").click(function () {
    $(".fancybox").eq(0).trigger("click");
    return false;
});
```

None of the options above will duplicate the first image as long as you don't use in the trigger the same selector bound to the fancybox gallery.

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jG8Tp/)</kbd>

Comment: Is it possible to use this external trigger to start the gallery at a specific image? I've been searching but I don't fully understand the answers sorry.

Comment: We tried the jumpto API method but we don't understand how to use it because although we see the correct image, it displays in the browser window and not within the fancybox gallery: ```$(".open-fancybox").eq(0).trigger("click")jumpto(3);```

Comment: Sorry got it by changing ```eq(0)``` to ```eq(3)``` to target the forth image. Cheers